# Why did the Jedi not know Anakin Skywalker had a secret marriage?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, anakin-skywalker

When young Anakin Skywalker first met the Jedi Council, Yoda told him the Jedi could read his mind and see his inner thoughts.

> See through you we can.

If the Jedi can read minds, why they did not know grown-up Anakin had secretly married Padme Amidala.

Are Jedi trained in how to block mind-readers?

Comment: Isn't there ample evidence that the Jedi Council were pretty inept at perceiving deception?

Comment: Because he kept it a secret.

Comment: They did miss that Palpatine was actually a Sith Lord

Comment: How do you know the Council didn't know? They are shown to be pretty lax about most things, why not that as well?

Answer (score 7):

Suppressing their emotions is a large part of the Jedi way after all so the masters wouldn't detect his joy at finally being married to Padme. I'd expect they learn other ways of protecting their thoughts as they'd be pretty ineffective against dark force users like the Sith otherwise. There must be exercises to strengthen the mind since Obi-Wan uses force persuasion in the very first film and mentions that the force can be used against people who are weak of mind.